# Partition sizes with high cardinality column (Timestamp) with Ingestion Time Clustering

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I am appending rows to a delta table once per day:

```
(df
.write
.mode("append")
.format("delta")
.save("/mytable")
)
```

On each append, a new partition file is created. The problem is that each partition is only around 1mb, so as this table grows, I will have thousands of tiny partitions.

[Databricks recommends](https://docs.databricks.com/tables/partitions.html#what-is-minimum-size-for-each-partition-in-a-table) that each partition be at least 1GB.

Each row has a different TimeStamp value. How can I confirm that [Ingestion Time Clustering](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/11/18/introducing-ingestion-time-clustering-dbr-112.html) has identified the TimeStamp column and is working?

Maybe it would make sense to create a "Month" or "Year" column and repartition by that so each partition is larger? Would ingestion time clustering on the TimeStamp column be relevant then? I know Ingestion Time Clustering is a good tool for high cardinality column, but it is useful for this case?